# Mosquitto MQTT Broker setup with authentication username password

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to configure Mosquitto MQTT broker on windows with Authentication with username and password.

I have added below line in mosquitto.conf file:

allow_anonymous false

username Test
remote_username Test

remote_password Test123

While running broker following error occurs:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto>mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf  -p
>   1883 Error: Invalid bridge configuration. Error found at
>   mosquitto.conf:750. Error: Unable to open configuration file.

**Without username and password I am able to start broker and connect with MQTTLens Client.**

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `remote_username` and `remote_password` options are for configuring bridges. You should look at the `password_file` option. For example

```
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
```

The generate the file with

```
mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/pwfile ashok
```

And add more users

```
mosquitto_passwd /etc/mosquitto/pwfile guest
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same programmatically using PHP or javascript?